# Ruby on Rails 6 Bootstrap undefined variable error on server restart

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem in rails 6 where when i restart my server I get Error: Undefined variable. If I comment out any scss variables in my files, refresh the page, un-comment the variables and refresh again everything works fine and I am able to use variables in my CSS files again. Im not really sure why this is happening and any help anyone can offer would be really appreciated.

Here is my application.scss file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 */

@import "custom_variables";
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
                                             
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
@import 'layouts';
@import 'themes';
@import 'typography';
@import 'states';
```

and here are the files I am using variables in:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints,"lg")) {
    .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints,"lg")) {
    .dropdown-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}

.footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
.bg-dark-red {
  background-color: $banner-color;
}

.navbar, .footer {
  background-color: $navbar-bg-color;
  
  a {
    color: $navbar-color;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: $navbar-hover-color;
  }

  .active {
    color: $navbar-active-color;
  }
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: $navbar-bg-color;
  
  a {
    color: $navbar-color;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: $navbar-hover-color;
    background-color: inherit;
  }

  .dropdown-divider {
    border-top-color: $dropdown-border-color;
  }
}

section.map {
  background-color: $map-bg-color;
}

.btn-primary {
  @include button-variant($primary-btn-color, darken($primary-btn-color, 7.5%), darken($primary-btn-color, 10%), lighten($primary-btn-color,5%), lighten($primary-btn-color, 10%), darken($primary-btn-color,30%));
}
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to stop this from occurring?

EDIT: I forgot to include the file where I am importing the variables, here it is:

```
$white: #fff;
$black: #000;
$primary-color: #FF0103;
$complementary-color: complement($primary-color);

$navbar-color: rgba($white, .55);
$navbar-bg-color: #343A40;
$navbar-hover-color: rgba($white, .75);
$dropdown-border-color: rgba($black, .15);
$navbar-active-color: $white;

$banner-color: $primary-color;
$primary-btn-color: #198754;
$map-bg-color: #E1E1E1;
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `*= require_self`? Sprockets directives tend to play havoc with SCSS. Its only really needed if you want to change the order of the files content relative to other files imported by Sprockets.

Comment: Just tried it now and still getting the same error. Would you recommend leaving that line out anyway still?

Comment: What is the file extension of the files your’re declaring your variables in?

Comment: Some of the variables are bootstrap variables so they are loaded from the bootsrap .scss files but i also have some custom variables that I am loading from a .scss.erb file, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this question is closed? Im being told its because Im not providing an error but I clearly am in the first line, also it says im not providing any desired behaviour but i think that it would be clear what the desired behaviour is. Thanks for any input anyone can give me

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same exact issue. It was so frustrating. First get rid of all the comments in the application.scss file especially the line that has `*= require_self`. Any file that uses bootstrap variables should have `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` at the top. The following will NOT work:

application.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'custom.scss"
```

custom.css:

```
body {
    background-color: $gray-200;
}
```

Instead move the line `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` from application.scss to custome.scss, then it will work as shown below:

custom.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
body {
    background-color: $gray-200;
}
```

Comment: This works but isn't there a better way of doing this?  If I have 100 SCSS files, aren't I essentially importing the entire bootstrap CSS library 100 times?  Or does the compiling somehow ignore duplications?